# Crashlytics firebase BigQuery (small) sample dataset wanted

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, dataset, crashlytics, sample

I have to develop a program to work on Crashlytics firebase BigQuery data, but our dev team still hasn't migrated our app from fabric.io to firebase.

Can somebody share a small dataset ( a couple of dozen entries would be ok) of Crashlytics firebase data which has been exported to BigQuery ?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#without_stack_traces

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [here you go](https://datastudio.google.com/open/1qJ2N2vzTpaoNqo46haT4vPOy6sPIY0rh).

As a heads up, you can view sample public datasets from the BigQuery dashboard, under Resources>Add Data>Explore Public Datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but unfortunately I con not open the link provided. The message I get is:
"Report cannot be viewed at this time or xxx@yyyyyyy.com does not have access."

Also within the public datasets, I can not find a Crashlytics Firebase data set.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Hey,

Sorry for the delayed response, I didn't get a notification since your reply wasn't a comment. It looks like you'd need to provide an email address for me to share that dataset with you. You can feel free to write into support(at)fabric(dot)com if you don't want to provide that on here.